# How dismiss keyboard without losing focus on ReactNative.( show cursor at least)

Tags: react-native, keyboard, cursor, textinput

I'm having an issue with customized keypad on react native, once the keyboard is dismissed, the cursor and on focus is lost.

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: you look at this(https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14045#issuecomment-407666552), the problem is not solved

Answer (score 0):

Created the expo snack example with  input ref focus return and keyboard dismiss events as concept that what you need.

You can look at the code and run it on device:
https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/keyboard

Comment: The keyboard will reappear when the textbox is focused